# How to show specific order details and all products which belongs only to that specific order on same view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

How to show specific order details and all products which belongs only to that specific order on same view? Trying this, but getting empty array when doing dd().
OrderController:

```
public function show(Order $order){
    $products = Product::where('order_id', $order);
    //dd($products);
    return view('order.view', ['order'=>$order, 'products'=>$products]);
}
```

web.php

```
    //Orders and products related routes
    Route::get('/order/{order}', 'OrderController@show')->name('order');
    Route::get('/orders/create', 'OrderController@create')->name('order.create');
    Route::post('/order', 'OrderController@store')->name('order.store');
    Route::get('/order', 'OrderController@index')->name('order.index');
    Route::delete('/order/{order}/destroy', 'OrderController@destroy')->name('order.destroy');
    Route::get('/order/{order}/edit', 'OrderController@edit')->name('order.edit');
    Route::put('/order/{order}/update', 'OrderController@update')->name('order.update');
 
    Route::get('/order/{order}/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.create');
    Route::post('/order/{order}/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Product.php

```
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Order.php

```
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Customer;
 
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
 
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
 
 
}
```

Comment: You need to use `get()` on your query `Product::where('order_id', $order)->get()`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it seems it's not good method, because in this case my $order variable is empty. How i should define show method in case to be able to get order details on view how it is now and also be able to using loop get $order->products->id..etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change the name of your route param to id to consistency and readability

```
Route::get('/order/{id}', 'OrderController@show')->name('order');
```

In view generate url for your route as

```
<a href="{{ route('order', [$id]) }}">Show Order</a>
```

And in controller you can get order details along with related products as

```
public function show($id){

    $order = Order::with('products')->find($id);
    
    return view('order.view', ['order'=>$order]);
}
```

And in view you can get collection of products from `$order->products`

Comment: Well actually I just realized another way -->    public function show(Order $order){
        return view('order.view', ['order'=>$order]);} and on the view.blade.php --->@foreach ($order->products as $product) as this solved the issue. But it seems your suggestion is more useful and easier to get id. Thank you!